# make all files private using aws-shell for S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-shell

I want to change the files of a bucket (all files) to private, so i'm wondering how to do it with aws-shell. I think that maybe the [`mv` command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html) can be useful to achieve this, but i cant figure out how to use it, because this is the first time that i use aws-shell.

#### Edit 1

I tried using `s3 mv s3://bucket s3://temporary --recursive --acl private`, but i needed to create another temporary bucket to make the swap. Because of this error:

> Cannot mv a file onto itself [...]

Is there a way to do this without creating a temporary bucket? I mean that this could cause charges for having transactions and space being used by duplicate files

Comment: Is the bucket public or are the individual files?

Comment: I make the bucket private but all the files still public :(

Answer (score 3):

You can **copy** the files onto themselves and change the Access Control List.

Test it out, but it would be something like:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket s3://bucket --recursive --acl private
```

Keep the source and destination the same.